# How to use "data" from a http.post angular request out of the success ?

Tags: angularjs, charts

I get some datas for a chart, and i need the max value of them.
In my success i get correctly this value in $scope.tempData, but how can i do to use it in the $scope.options scaleStepWidth?

Here is my code

```
    $scope.truc = [];
    $scope.tac = [];
    $scope.tic;
    $scope.tempData = 0;
    $scope.chargerStats = function () {

        var idProd = document.getElementById("idProduit").value;

        $http.post("{{path('pfcrm_phone_factory_graphe_nbventesproduitpartemps')}}", {id: idProd})
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.truc = $scope.data['datasets'];
                    $scope.tac = $scope.truc[0].data;

                    $scope.tempData = Math.max.apply(null, $scope.tac);

                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    alert("Erreur pour l'affichage des graphiques");
                });

    };


    var steps = 3;
    // Chart.js Options
    $scope.options = {
        // Sets the chart to be responsive
        responsive: true,
        // Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
        showScale: true,
        // Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
        scaleOverride: true,
        // Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
        scaleSteps: steps,
        // Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
        scaleStepWidth: 500,
        //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
        scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        //String - Colour of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        //Number - Width of the grid lines
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
        barShowStroke: true,
        //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
        barStrokeWidth: 2,
        //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
        barValueSpacing: 5,
        //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
        barDatasetSpacing: 1
    };
});
```

Thanks a lot .

Comment: what you mean with extract? you wanna display in the html?

Comment: no need of `{{}}`inside controller use `$scope.variableName` thats my guess..what exactly you want?

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner ^^ , my request is working, and if i "console.log" my $score.tempData in the success it's it returned the good value, but out of the success i can't get it . And i don't understand why .

Comment: @VincentCONGY, how are we supposed to help if we don't know even what data type is returned? You might be a beginner in Angular, Javascript or coding, but that is not an argument for not investing time to ask a good question - see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what does `out of the success i can't get it` mean? ajax is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by putting my $scope.option in the success. 
Thanks a lot for your help.